# How do I write man pages?

Tags: documentation

How do I write a man page?

Where can I find a reference of all formatting codes?

Are there any good tutorials on writing man pages?

What is the most convenient way to write a man page? Should I enter it directly in a text editor? Are there WYSIWYG editors? Or should I write it in a different format and then convert?

What rules should a good man page follow?

Comment: This question appears to be too broad. It has only succeeded in attracting a bunch of link-only answers and a few unsupported opinions.

Comment: `man man`, `man groff`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a few web pages that will help get you started:

- [Creating and Formatting Man Pages](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/ups/ReferenceManual/html/manpages.html)
- [Creating Your Own MAN Page](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/creatingman.htm)
- [Create Your own Man Page](http://anaturb.net/create_man_p.htm)
- [How to Write a Man Page](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs701/Handouts/man_pages.html)
- [What you need to know to write man pages](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/34212)

A couple of useful tools:

- [txt2man](http://mvertes.free.fr/)
- [help2man](http://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/)

Answer (score 6):

There are tools for writing man pages that bypass troff formatting. manpages are a small, well delimited language and easy to target.

Two popular tools are:

- [xmltoman](http://packages.debian.org/sid/xmltoman), a small and well structured xml language that can generate manpages and html. It is used by Lennart Poettering's projects, [syrep](http://git.0pointer.de/?p=syrep.git;a=blob;f=man/syrep.1.xml.in;hb=HEAD) and [pulseaudio for example](http://git.0pointer.de/?p=pulseaudio.git;a=blob;f=man/pulseaudio.1.xml.in;hb=HEAD).
- [asciidoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/), [used by git for example](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/git-notes.txt;hb=HEAD).

[yodl](http://yodl.sourceforge.net/yodl04.html#l109) and [zoem](http://micans.org/mcl/man/mcl.azm) seem to be other nice formats in this space.

All in all I'd recommend xmltoman because it's a very manpage specific dsl that will guide you closely.

Comment: "dsl" == "domain specific language"?

Comment: yes (da. si. 15 chars.)

Comment: Another good option is [ronn](http://rtomayko.github.io/ronn/ronn.1.html), which reads the more-widely-used Markdown text markup language.

Answer (score 5):

I have written a rather extensive blog article about the topic, which you can find here:

> http://2buntu.com/articles/1034/how-to-write-a-manpage/

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could at least summarize the article here -- links alone are worthless once the linked page inevitably moves or disappears.

Comment: I do not agree with Caleb. This is the web. The web is based on links, and stackexchange does not carry any special exception to this. Copying content is counterproductive.  Whatever bad thing can happen to *that* page or document can also happen to *this* one.  We cannot hoard scraped copies of all content just because the rest of the web might disappear. (Leave that job to sites like the wayback machine).

Comment: Kaz, you may not agree, but Caleb's comment is definitely ServerFault best-practice.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any IDEs or tutorials, but you can start by copying an existing man page and modify it to suit your needs.

For a reference of the groff language with MAN macros (which is what is used by a man page) consult the **groff_man** man page, or [read it online here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/groff_man)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [ronn project](https://github.com/rtomayko/ronn). Its a [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) to man page generator. It can also generate the man pages in html, like [this](http://rtomayko.github.io/ronn/ronn.1.html).

I like the idea of writing all my software documentation in one format. Markdown IMO is a good choice